# How to add comment in my facebook page post using api

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to add comment in my facebook page post using graph api if I know page id and post id?

Comment: Please, read the docs before ask. Also, this is an off-topic question.

Comment: I think [this](https://ishort.gq/gvK8QHy) can help you => https://ishort.gq/gvK8QHy

Answer (score 0):

Following links helped.

`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v13.0/comment`

`https://graph.facebook.com/[ POST_FBID ]/comments/?access_token=[ ACCESS_TOKEN ]&message=[ MESSAGE]`